# Как получить данные из таблицы за определённый период времени в sqlite3?

Tags: python, sqlite3

Как составить запрос, чтобы получить все из базы данных за определенный период времени, например с '2022-03-10' по '2022-03-14'

Вот как я создаю таблицу

```
conn = sql.connect(base)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS portion(
                            datatime TEXT,
                            meal_time TEXT,
                            calories_portion REAL,
                            protein_portion REAL,
                            fats_portion REAL,
                            carbohydrates_portion REAL
                            );
                        """)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Вот так я добавляю данные в таблицу

```
data_kbju_portion = ['2022-03-12', 'Ужин', 334.0, 10.8, 1.3, 69.9]

con = sql.connect(base)
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("INSERT INTO portion (datatime, meal_time, calories_portion, protein_portion, "
                    "fats_portion, carbohydrates_portion"
                    ") VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);", data_kbju_portion)
con.commit()
con.close()
```

таблица:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться стандартным определением диапазона выборки:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * from portion WHERE datatime BETWEEN '2022-03-10' and '2022-03-14'")
```

Умышленно или нет, но вы корректно задали даты при занесении данных в таблицу. поэтому впредь и далее придерживайтесь этого формата (YYYY-MM-DD), в противном случае ваши даты будут распознаваться как строки, и результат будет непредсказуем.